# Slider Images showing one below other when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm using a slider to show Images in a web page. Code works fine and the images slide properly. But when I add images dynamically via jquery, the images are stacking one below other instead of sliding. What could be the reason?

Here is the code which works fine, when I statically link images to the slider.

```
    <div class="slider" data-arrows="true" >
                 <ul class="slides" id="slider" >
                   <li> <img alt="Image" src="img/work-1.jpg" /> </li>
                   <li> <img alt="Image" src="img/work-1.jpg" /> </li>
                   <li> <img alt="Image" src="img/work-1.jpg" /> </li>
                   <li> <img alt="Image" src="img/work-1.jpg" /> </li>

                 </ul>
   </div>
```

This is where I'm stuck when I add images dynamically via append the images are stacking one below the other.

```
 for(var i=0; i<10;i++){

        var  x = '  <li>'+
                '<img alt="Image" src="img/work-1.jpg" />'+
                '</li>';

  $("#slider").append(x);

  }
```

Comment: Can you create & share a jsbin/jsfiddle link,for better undderstanding?

Comment: May be your slider  function works on the images which are present at the time  of initialization ,adding more object needs reinitialization of slider for desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using flexbox, you could do something like this with your css:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var x = '  <li>' +
      '<img alt="Image" src="https://placebear.com/g/100/100" />' +
      '</li>';
    $("#slider").append(x);
  }
})
```

```css
.slides {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" data-arrows="true">
  <ul class="slides" id="slider">
    <li> <img alt="Image" src="https://placebear.com/g/100/100" /> </li>
    <li> <img alt="Image" src="https://placebear.com/g/100/100" /> </li>
    <li> <img alt="Image" src="https://placebear.com/g/100/100" /> </li>
    <li> <img alt="Image" src="https://placebear.com/g/100/100" /> </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you need the slides to wrap, you can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your `.slides` css selector.

Comment: I'm using flickity, came with the theme I purchased by default. Tried adding the above code to my css, all the images get stacked into a single image. Adding flex-wrap: wrap makes them stack them one below the other, back to my previous error.